# Let$ f : [0, 1]^2 \to R$ such that $f(x, y)$ is continuous in $x$ for each fixed $y$ and conversely also. Is $f $ continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let$ f : [0, 1]^2 \to R$ such that $f(x, y)$ is continuous in $x$ for each fixed $y$ and continuous in $y$ for each fixed x. Does it follow that $f$ is continuous?

Comment: Does it? What's your first guess and why? Also, you shouldn't need MSE to answer this question - it's a very standard example/counterexample type of question in analysis. Google would probably yield a quick answer; if you have Gelbaum and Olmsted's classic *Counterexamples in Analysis* this would be even better.

Comment: You may consider a function like $f(x,y)=\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$ when $(x,y)\ne (0,0)$ and $f(0,0)=0$.